# Project Lombok - the method is undefined for the type Geofence

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, lombok

I have included Project Lombok in my Gradle dependency like this:

```
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.0'
```

I have annotated all my getters and setters with

```
@Getter @Setter
```

But now I cannot build my project at all.  I am getting errors like this:

> Error:C:\Users\Igor\Workspace\Geofencing\libraries\my-sdk\src\main\java\com\sdk\MyMonitor.java:93: The method getLatitude() is undefined for the type Geofence

But I know for a fact that **getLatitude** is defined by Lombok in my Geofence.java class!

Comment: Did this not help? http://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html

Comment: I am seeing this issue reported on: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77902.  Apparently it is a problem with Android Studio annotations processing inside of library projects.  This is frustrating!

Answer (score 3):

I also have missing getters and setters in a Spring Data project. I fixed the problem by downgrading Lombok to version 1.14.8, see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok